# Wondering why matplotlib pyplot won't adjust margins

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add margins to the plot so that rather than having the `0.0` be at the edge corner, the `0.0` is slightly away from the corner. I'm looking at [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.margins) and it would seem that adding this line `plt.margins(x_margin, y_margin)` should add padding. My output below however still is the same regardless of that function call and still is missing margin padding.

[image]

Example code to produce:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1], [0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 1, 0.15, 0.3])
# Create a 10% (0.1) and 10% (0.1) padding in the
# x and y directions respectively.
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two contradicting statements here:
`plt.axis([0, 1, 0.15, 0.3])` sets the x-axes limits to `(0,1)`. This cannot be undone with `plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)`.

Depending on what the aim is, you may

- leave the axes to autoscale and set `plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)` to get 10% margins.
- Calculate your desired limits taking into account `10%` margins; e.g. as

  ```
  lim = [0, 1, 0.15, 0.3]
  plt.axis( [lim[i] +2*(i%2-.5)*(lim[i//2+1]-lim[i//2])*0.1 for i in range(4)] )
  ```

Answer (score 2):

After plotting your data, try this instead:

```
x0, x1, y0, y1 = plt.axis()
margin_x = 0.1 * (x1-x0)
margin_y = 0.1 * (y1-y0)
plt.axis((x0 - margin_x,
          x1 + margin_x,
          y0 - margin_y,
          y1 + margin_y))
```

Comment: Did it help? Or are you wondering to do it specifically with plt.margin?

Comment: The margin you use here is not a 10% margin but a margin of 0.1 dataunits.

Comment: Thank you Dario! it was helpful but I think the ImportanceOfBeingErnest had the more "correct" answer